# Are some algorithms inherently recursive?

Tags: algorithms, trees, recursion, tail-recursion

Are some algorithms inherently recursive?
As in, rewriting it in tail-recursive/iterative form with a stack is still needed, and there is no way to do it otherwise.

I am asking because I struggled to implement the function `stringsMatchingPrefix` on a Trie tail-recursively without a stack. The `stringsMatchingPrefix` problem is: given a string P, find all the words in the trie with the prefix P.

Comment: Can you explain what `stringsMatchingPrefix` is? We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean "like" in your title and question?

Comment: It's difficult to argue that a given algorithm needs some particular technique, since that requires us to precisely define that technique so as to rule out any trivial modifications to it (and for that matter, we also have to define what we mean by "[that particular] algorithm" - specifically, we need some notion of when two algorithms are the same, [and that's surprisingly intricate](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1243948484)).

Comment: However, we can get somewhat satisfying results by showing that a given function we're trying to compute is not in a particular complexity class: e.g. the fact that the Ackermann function is not primitive recursive does in some sense say that there is no algorithm computing it which doesn't use "high-level" recursion (or something morally equivalent to that).